# Why doesn't my IF BETWEEN statement in ABAP work?

Tags: abap

My IF <provided_number> BETWEEN <given_number> AND <given_number> does not work on numbers it should.
This is the part of my code that does't work:

```
IF wa_ini-vbelv BETWEEN '1700000000' AND '1789999999'.
```

My code just completely ignores this part. For the number '1780000000', which, I reckon, should fall into the statement, it just completely skips my IF.
Instead of adding any code for that IF, I tried simply assigning a strict value of '0000000000' for every value meeting that IF's requirements - it doesn't work. That IF is just ignored every single time.

---

Perhaps the above is enough tor resolve my issue. If not -> see below for a specific description of what I am trying to do and my code. I think it might be a lot - so thank you in advance.

---

The idea of my code is to extract invoices' numbers from VBFA for the provided document number. VBFA 'contains' the document flow - it has two columns important to me here:

- vbelv -> the previous document in relation to the provided one,
- vbeln -> the next document in relation to the provided one.

Which means that for the document flow looking like '1 - 2 - 3 - 4', being provided '4' and wanting to display '2', I would need to first SELECT VBELV where VBELN = 4 (save '3' to a variable), then SELECT VBELV where VBELN = my_variable_holding_3 and then I end up with '2' I wanted. That explains what my code is supposed to be doing.

I'll also mention that one VBELV can have many VBELNs… Next documents branch out of the previous one. It's basically traversing a tree with a lot of branches. That's why I need to specify the range of values the VBELV or VBELV that's being reached for needs to be in.

The idea is just to find invoices which are documents starting with 1* and return then with the exception of invoices starting with 17* for which I need to look even deeper and find document 18* (because 17* means there's an another type of an invoice I need to get).

I am also adding a part of my code for context. Perhaps it will be required to examine my problem. I am not adding all of it, because I don't think it's relevant to the problem. Also, everything apart from the problem with 17* works without an issue.
NRFAKTURYDOWZ is a name of the column I am displaying the output in (this is a query in SQ02).

```
TABLES: vbfa.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_vbf,
  vbelv TYPE vbfa-vbelv,
  END OF ty_vbf.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty2_vbf,
  vbeln TYPE vbfa-vbeln,
END OF ty2_vbf.

*These are used throughout the code, including the part I did not include in this section.
DATA: wa_ini TYPE ty_vbf,
      wa_prev TYPE ty_vbf,
      wa_next TYPE ty2_vbf,
      wa_v178 TYPE ty_vbf,
      wa_n178 TYPE ty2_vbf.


*Selecting the first 'previous document' where vbeln = provided number.
SELECT SINGLE vbelv
FROM vbfa
INTO wa_ini
WHERE vbeln = BKPF-XBLNR
  AND vbeln >= '1000000000'
  AND vbeln <= '9999999999'.


*Selecting the 'next document' of the previously selected vbelv.
SELECT SINGLE vbeln
FROM vbfa
INTO wa_next
WHERE vbelv = wa_ini-vbelv.


*Making sure the initially selected VBELV is within the proper range.
IF wa_ini-vbelv BETWEEN '1000000000' AND '2999999999'.
*Here is the guy that won't work and won't stop driving me nuts.
  IF wa_ini-vbelv BETWEEN '1700000000' AND '1789999999'.
    SELECT SINGLE vbelv
      FROM vbfa
      INTO wa_v178
      WHERE vbeln = wa_ini-vbelv.
        SELECT SINGLE vbeln
        FROM vbfa
        INTO wa_n178
        WHERE vbelv = wa_v178-vbelv
        AND vbeln BETWEEN '1880000000' AND '1889999999'.
          IF NOT wa_n178 IS INITIAL.
            NRFAKTURYDOWZ = wa_n178-vbeln.
          ELSE.
            NRFAKTURYDOWZ = ''.
          ENDIF. 
ENDIF.
 NRFAKTURYDOWZ = wa_ini-vbelv.
ELSEIF.<br><mooooooreeeee coooooodeeeee>
```

If you made it here, allow me to express my most sincere gratitude. I am fully aware that's a lot of stuff and your time is precious. I am really thankful and wish you a great day.

Cheers,
Bartek

Comment: There's nothing special about `BETWEEN`, your code should work. Probably there is something at runtime that makes it wrong. Using the debugger, display the value in hexadecimal to make sure that it's exactly what you think it is. Character renderings are sometimes "misleading" (zero may not be zero), but hexadecimal never lies.

Comment: `DATA value LIKE vbfa-vbelv. value = '1780000000'. IF value BETWEEN '1700000000' AND '1789999999'.` works for me ...

Comment: Thank to both of you for dedicating the time and effort to looking into my problem. I managed to resolve it and posted the answer below.
I will keep your advices in mind for the future, so thanks for them too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it.

If you take a look at my code, you'll see that at the bottom of my "outer" IF statement, the 'NRFAKTURYDOWZ = wa_ini-vbelv.' part is not wrapped in ELSE section… Which means that it always overwrote any value that I manager to extract previously. That created the impression that my "inner" IF statement was completely ignored… because whatever it did, I ordered my code to just overwrite the value anyway. :-/

I will probably delete the question later. I am not sure if it's going to be helpful to anyone in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Yes, you're right, it can be deleted. It's something than you can only find by debugging your code, and the symptoms can vary a lot. This kind of question can be deleted. Otherwise, it could be closed as off-topic because not reproducible or caused by "typo" (i.e. buggy code).